# How do I set up persistent authentication in a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, authentication

All sorts of mobile apps - Gmail, Facebook, Pandora - have some persistent mechanism of authentication that enables a user to set up credentials once and then use them to automatically authenticate with their remote service in the future.  I'm probably blind, but I can't seem to find a tutorial anywhere out there that explains in simple terms how to properly do this on a mobile app.

How do I build this functionality?  A link to a simple tutorial would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Deva said, SharedPreferences is a perfect quick and easy solution for creating this feature. Usually when I want to implement this I follow this simple  flow:

Logging In:
When the user logs in save the user id (it can really be any unique identifier) into Shared Preferences. This information should now be available so that your app can recall it later

Rebooting:
When the app reboots it should check to see if any user id is saved in Shared Preferences. If not, then there is no one to automatically log in. If there is, then reload the user information using the user id from the server or whatever.

Logging Out:
When the user logs out make sure you delete the key/value pair from Shared Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

For this probabely you can try a [SharedPrefrence](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). The first time user enters his details , the values get stored locally if the user is authenticated and every consecutive time you can check the same prefrence if the value is already there directly pick the value and invoke the service for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [KeyChain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) is service ment exactly for such a scenario. it enables a persistent, secure and easy to use storage.
Good tutorial (+ demo application) [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html)